# Exclude current custom post on single post

Tags: posts, loop, query

I'm trying to exclude the current custom post that is viewed from a list. I've tried with `exclude` but it still displays it.

Here is the code I have on `single-works.php`:

```
<?php
$currentID = get_the_ID();
$recent = new WP_Query( 'post_type=works&exclude=' . $currentID . '&showposts=5' );
while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
?>

  <li><?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the [`WP_Query` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for a full list and explanation of parameters. The one you want in this case is `post__not_in`.

```
$recent = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'works'
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in' => array( $currentID )
    )
);
```

Comment: Also `showposts` is depreciated and should only use  `posts_per_page`!

Comment: @Sumit `showposts` is **NOT** depreciated. The documentation is incorrect. `showposts` is however replaced by `posts_per_page`. `showposts` is converted to `posts_per_page` inside `WP_Query`.